# get image from image view?

Tags: iphone, image, imageview

Can I get an image from image view? Please tell me what the code looks like..

Comment: do you want uiimage from uiimageview?

Comment: yes..need to assign a image to UIImage image =" myimageView image";

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
UIImageView *imageview; //Assign to your image view
[imageview image];
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImageView_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006889

Comment: @Sharmain [imageview image]; returns the UIImage stored in the UIImageView "imageview"

Comment: @RTS that doesn't assign the image to anything though. So your statement retrieves the image but doesn't put it anywhere. In effect, it does nothing.

Comment: @Jamie I would assume she would wrap it in something else... Like she could write [[imageview image]drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0)];

Comment: UIImage* myImage = [imageview image]; it worked successfully...thank you for ur help...

Comment: @Sharmain, this should really be a separate question but... your code would say button.hidden = true; where button is your UIButton.

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
UIImage *setImg=[ UIImage imageNamed:@"testImg.png"];
```

To display the image in imageView

```
UIImageView *imgView=[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:setImg];
```

To get Image from imageView

```
UIImage *getImg=imgView.image;
```

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on what you want to do with the image, but if you just want to get a pointer to the image then you would do this.

```
UIImage *imageIWant = imageView.image;
```

Comment: i need to save the image which is displayed in my image view  to documents directory..can u help me please..any sample codes...

Comment: Something like this...NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedImage.png"];
UIImage *image = imageView.image; 
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];

Comment: Oh and just so you know, you can only accept one answer as the accepted answer.. :), however, you can upvote as many as you like.

Comment: @Jaimie From the level of the discussion you can infer the level of the participants. At the lowest end of the scale you get a lot of crazy voters.

Comment: Thanks Nikolai. Guess I haven't been around that long on these forums, really.

Comment: may i know that can i save the image which is displayed in my image view to documents directory with user defined name

Comment: Sure..just replace the name of the string @"savedImage.png" to an NSString * that you get from the user.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have an `UIImageView` instance **imageview**.

Use the below to get the `UIImage`

```
UIImage* myImage = [imageview image];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImageView *imageView;
UIImage *img = imageView.image;
```

img is image from UIImageView imageView.